# How do I get a list of document ID’s from Firestore

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I need a list of document ID’s from a collection, so I can use it in a DropdownButton, which will select the specific document.

The code below prints out the doc.id for each document in the collection.

```
void getDevices () async {
  var firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.email;
  print('firebaseUser: $firebaseUser');
  await firestoreInstance.collection(devices).where('email', isEqualTo: '$firebaseUser').get().then((value) {
     value.docs.forEach((element) {print(element.id);});
  });
```

I need the doc.id for each document in a list.

*The solution is*

```
  Future<List<dynamic>> getDevices() async {
    var firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.email;
    var query = await firestoreInstance
        .collection(devices)
        .where('email', isEqualTo: '$firebaseUser')
        .get();

    List<String> _documentsIds = query.docs.map((doc) => doc.id).toList();
    return _documentsIds;
  }
```

The second part of my question were as how to use the Future, it's as

```
Container(
                    width: 380,
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24.0),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        border: Border.all(
                            color: Colors.lightBlueAccent, width: 1.0),
                        borderRadius: kBorderRadius),
                    child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                        child: FutureBuilder<List>(
                            future: getDevices(),
                            builder: (BuildContext context,
                                AsyncSnapshot<List<dynamic>> snapshot) {
                              if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                                return const Text(
                                  'Waiting Devices',
                                );
                              } else {
                                return DropdownButton(
                                  borderRadius: kBorderRadius,
                                  iconSize: 40,
                                  elevation: 16,
                                  hint: const Text(
                                    'Safegaurd Devices',
                                  ),
                                  onChanged: (value) {
                                    setState(() {
                                      selectedDeviceValue = value.toString();
                                      setState(() {
                                        selectedDeviceValue;
                                        getDeviceSettings();
                                      });
                                    });
                                  },
                                  value: selectedDeviceValue,
                                  items: snapshot.data
                                      ?.map((_documentsIds) =>
                                          DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                                            value: _documentsIds,
                                            child: Text(_documentsIds),
                                          ))
                                      .toList(),
                                );
                              }
                            })),
                  )
```

Answer (score 1):

To summarise the solution from the comments:

```dart
void getDevices () async {
  var firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.instance
    .currentUser?.email;
  var snapshot =  await firestoreInstance.collection(devices)
    .where('email', isEqualTo: '$firebaseUser')
    .get();
  var idList = snapshot.docs.map(doc=> doc.id).toList();

// rest of your code here

}
```

Note* when using async/await, you must use the `await` keyword without `.then()`

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Do I call the ``` getDevices (); ``` in the '''   void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getCurrentUser();
    getDevices();
  } ''' to make idList avalible when I build my Widget? As it seems like it is not available in my Widget as it returns null.

Comment: @JohanScheepers code blocks with tripple back ticks don’t work in comments. Please use single back ticks instead. The getDevices function is async- You will need to use a Future Builder when waiting for async data to load. See the [Flutter Firebase Docs](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/) for usage.

Comment: @JohanScheepers has the provided solution with the Future Builder solved your issue?

Comment: Still trying to figure it out.

`  Future<List<String>> getDevices() async {
    var firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.email;
    print('firebaseUser: $firebaseUser');
    var query = await firestoreInstance
        .collection(devices)
        .where('email', isEqualTo: '$firebaseUser')
        .get();
    var _documentsIds = query.docs.map((doc) => doc.id).toList();
    print('_documentsIds: $_documentsIds');

    return _documentsIds;
  }
`

Comment: Not sure what to do here

`
Container(
  width: 380,
  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24.0),
  child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
    child: DropdownButton(
      hint: const Text(
        'Devices',
      ),
      onChanged: (value) {
        setState(() {});
        });
      },
      value: selectedValue,
      items: _documentsIds?.map((itemsList) {
        return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
          value: itemsList,
          child: Text(itemsList),
        );
      }).toList(),
    ),
  ),
)
`

Comment: @JohanScheepers it is very difficult to see your code when it is both commented, and not formatted as code. Please edit your original question with the new code, appropriately marked as dart.

Comment: I hope I have update the question correctly. I found the answer, so the solution is at the end of my question. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like:

```
void getDevices () async {
  var firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.email;
  print('firebaseUser: $firebaseUser');
 var query = await firestoreInstance.collection(devices).where('email', isEqualTo: ' 
 $firebaseUser').get();
 List documentsIds = query.docs.map((doc)=>doc.id); 
 });
```

Comment: Thank you ---- If use 'List documentsIds = query.docs.map((doc)=>doc.id);' flutter throws a error and recommends I use 'Iterable documentsIds = query.docs.map((doc)=>doc.id);'. Iterable is not a List,<String> thought. How do I use it in my DropdownButton ```items: itemsList.map((listItem) {
                          return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                            value: listItem,
                            child: Text(listItem),
                          );```

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake you should do this instead: List documentsIds = query.docs.map((doc)=>doc.id).toList();